# Why can't my AWS Lambda node JS app access my MongoDB Atlas cluster?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aws-lambda, mongodb-atlas

**Context :**

I have just created a Node.JS application and deployed it with the Serverless Framework on AWS Lambda.

**Problem :**

I would like that application to be able to access my (free tier) MongoDB Atlas Cluster. For this I am using `mongoose`.

**Setup :**

I have got a IAM User with AdministratorAccess rights. This user has been authorized on my MongoDB Cluster.
I am using the `authMechanism=MONGODB-AWS`, therefore using the Token and Secret of that IAM user. The password has been correctly "url encoded".

This is the piece of code used to create a connection :

```
const uri = "mongodb+srv://myIAMtoken:myIAMsecret@cluster0.tfws6.mongodb.net/DBNAME?authSource=%24external&authMechanism=MONGODB-AWS&retryWrites=true&w=majority"

mongoose.connect(uri, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
```

When I run this code on my laptop, the connection is made and I can retrieve the data needed.
However when I deploy this exact same code on AWS Lambda (through Serverless), I get this response :

```
    message "Internal server error"
```

The trace on CloudWatch looks like this :

```
{
"errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection",
"errorMessage": "MongoError: bad auth : aws sts call has response 403",
"reason": {
    "errorType": "MongoError",
    "errorMessage": "bad auth : aws sts call has response 403",
    "code": 8000,
    "ok": 0,
    "codeName": "AtlasError",
    "name": "MongoError",
    "stack": [
        "MongoError: bad auth : aws sts call has response 403",
        "    at MessageStream.messageHandler (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:268:20)",
        "    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:314:20)",
        "    at processIncomingData (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:144:12)",
        "    at MessageStream._write (/var/task/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)",
        "    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:403:12)",
        "    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:387:5)",
        "    at MessageStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:318:11)",
        "    at TLSSocket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:718:22)",
        "    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)",
        "    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)",
        "    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:272:9)",
        "    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:213:10)",
        "    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)"
    ]
},
"promise": {},
"stack": [
    "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: MongoError: bad auth : aws sts call has response 403",
    "    at process.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:35:15)",
    "    at process.emit (events.js:314:20)",
    "    at processPromiseRejections (internal/process/promises.js:209:33)",
    "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:98:32)"
]
}
```

I thought it was a network access issue from AWS, so I tried fetching "http://google.com" , no problem, my node app could access the page and provide the response. My app has an internet access but cannot reach my MongoDB cloud instance. My MongoDB cluster is accessible from any IP address.

This is reaching the limits of my knowledge :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using an iam type mongodb user then you don't need the username + password in the connection string.

```
const uri = "mongodb+srv://cluster0.tfws6.mongodb.net/DBNAME?authSource=$external&authMechanism=MONGODB-AWS&retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

when you invoke your lambda connecting to the mongodb cluster, the iam role that it will be using will be the execution role of the lambda

```
"arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:role/SLS_SERVICE_NAME-ENVIRONMENT-AWS_REGION-lambdaRole"
```

```
"arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/awesome-service-dev-us-east-1-lambdaRole"
```

check the default iam section of sls framework:
https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/iam/#the-default-iam-role

Comment: Alright thank you soooo much for this, definitely a step in the right direction. I would appreciate a lot if you could point me to the way of allowing this "role" to access my mongodb cluster on atlas ? 
I had an "IAM" user registered and allowed on mongodb, which was using the "TOKEN" and "SECRET" in the connection url string. But Im not sure how to proceed with this role that is being used by default, it's not a user that I can allow on mongo

Comment: in mongodb atlas navigate to your project, choose your cluster, go to database access on the left sidebar and create an IAM type user there with the permissions to read or readWrite to your database. The iam rola arn of that user should be the above mentioned. "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:role/SLS_SERVICE_NAME-ENVIRONMENT-AWS_REGION-lambdaRole"

Comment: @NassimBen let me know if at the end you were able to solve your problem or not and if my answer was helpful enough.

btw. the username + password type of user creation works the same way as the iam type, the difference is that you will have to add the urlencoded username+password into the connection string and the authSource will be admin, instead of the $external one.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

Comment: it did fix my problem, your answer was complete and clear, very helpful. The only issue with this authentication mechanism is that the connection string is different when I want to test my application offline (using user+pwd) and when I deploy it. I guess I can use .env variables to deal with that.

Comment: if you run `aws sts get-caller-identity` in the terminal and you get the arn of your local user, you can create an other iam user with the same permissions as the service user.
alternatively you can also create a username+password based user and handle the different connection strings in your codebase. Choice is yours, I'd do the first option.

Comment: Thank you again! The arn of my local iam user is already authorized on my mongo cluster. However it requires the token and secret in the connection string. 
It's alright I am now using two different strings to connect and managing them with the process.env.IS_OFFLINE environment variable.  :-) Thanks again for your kind help.